Error when importing svelte.ts into a .svelte file
I'm working on an Svelte application and trying to setup a rune "state" storage in its own separate file so it can be reused, but when trying to import on a .svelte component, I get a compilation error.
"Svelte: Module './TopBar.svelte' has no exported member menuButtonVisible"
// TopBar.svelte.ts
export const menuButtonVisible = $state(false);

// TopBar.svelte
<script lang="ts">
...
import { menuButtonVisible } from './TopBar.svelte';
...
</script>

I'm basically trying to do the same as explained over here
https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte/stores#When-to-use-stores
Note that when I import regular .ts files, I don't get that error. So, it looks like there should be some configuration missing to process .svelte.ts files?
https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte/svelte-js-files

You will need to wrap the value in an object, primitives cannot be exported from modules and changed (the value will only be copied once).

Ok, noted. But even when using the exact same code from the example in the link, I get same error. When importing from a .ts file which is not a svelte.ts, it works fine, but then I cannot use runes

If there also is a component with the same prefix, you need to supply an extension as well. Auto-imports can get this wrong.
import { menuButtonVisible } from './TopBar.svelte.js';

You can also import './TopBar.svelte.ts' if you enable it in the tsconfig.json via allowImportingTsExtensions.

This was the issue. I renamed the .svelte.ts file different from the svelte component (e.g. TopBarStore.svelte.ts) and it worked. Thanks.
